# Error al llamar método de Web Service

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webservice

Hice un método en un Web Service hecho con C# y me da un error al llamarlo desde JavaScript.

**Web Service:**

```
namespace PortalClientes{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Funciones : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string sendMail(string CIF)
        {
            Capa_Negocio.Usuarios cnUsuario = new Usuarios();

            if (cnUsuario.getEmailFirebird(CIF) == false)
            {
                return "Error: No se ha podido obtener el E-Mail";
            }

            else if (cnUsuario.Email != null || cnUsuario.Email != String.Empty)
            {
                if (CapaUtiles.Utiles.SendMailForgetPassword(cnUsuario.Email, 
                    cnUsuario.Cif) == true)
                {                  
                    return "El Mail se ha enviado correctamente";
                }
                else
                {                  
                    return "Error: No se ha podido enviar el mail";
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }

            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#butEnviarMail").click(function () {
    enviaMail();
});

function enviaMail() {

    var textcif = $("[id*='CIF']").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Funciones.asmx/sendMail",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{CIF:'12345678a'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: env,
        error: errorAjax
        });

    function env(msg){
        if (msg=="OK"){
            $("#CIF").load("LinkEnviado.aspx");
        }
        else{
            alert(msg);
        }
    }
    function errorAjax() {
        alert("Error ajax");
    }
}
```

Muestra el mensaje "`Error ajax`", saben a que se puede deber o si tengo algún error en la llamada.

Comment: ¿La dirección `Funciones.asmx/sendMail` la puedes consumir desde el navegador?

Comment: Perdona, pero no sé a que te refieres con consumir desde el navegador. Si te refieres a ponerlo en la url del navegador, me sale Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. No se encuentra el recurso

Comment: @wuassa en un navegador como Chrome o Internet Explorer pega en la barra de dirección `Funciones.asmx/sendMail`, dependiendo de lo que se muestre es como podremos ir viendo qué cosas podemos corregir

Comment: Vale. Me da error de servidor en la apliacion , Formato de solicitud no reconocido para la dirección URL, finaliza de manera inesperada en '/sendMail'.  Otra cosa, el webmethod no lo he declarado en static, pero al declararlo en static la conosola me da el siguiente error :POST http://localhost:55538/Account/Funciones.asmx/sendMail 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Bien, ahora requerimos utilizar Fiddle, ¿alguna vez lo has usado? Es un software justo para poder hacer pruebas en el consumo de servicios (entre otras cosas), es sencillo de usar, una vez instalado selecciona la pestaña `Composer`, en la barra de dirección pon la URL de tu servicio ASMX, y en el tipo de petición ponle POST, ahora dale el botón `Execute` y veamos el resultado que te entrega al consumir el servicio

Comment: Eso significa que existe un error interno y no encuentra el servicio (deduzco esto porque accedes a la dirección `localhost:55538` la cual solo existe mientras corres de forma local tu servicio), lo que yo haría sería publicar el servicio ya sea de forma local o en algún server en el cuál tengas acceso de esta forma ya estaría corriendo el servicio y lo puedes consumir desde cualquier punto en el que tengas acceso

Comment: si pongo en la barra del Fiddler :http://localhost:55538/Account/Funciones.asmx/sendMail y le doy execute con POST , me da el siguiente error : HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - DNS Lookup Failed

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51477/discussion-between-flxtr-and-wuasaa).

Comment: @wuasaa tu pregunta no aclara cual es el error que te arroja, debido a que no defines bien la función de error. Si lo defines como `function errorAjax(error){ alert(error); }` al menos te hubiera indicado el error al invocar por `Ajax` para ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

Asegúrate de agregar en **web.config** los protocolos que va a utilizar tu *webservice*.
Añade al **web.config** las siguientes líneas dentro de la sección **system.web**.

```
<webServices>
 <protocols>
  <add name="HttpPost">
  <add name="HttpGet">
 </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Answer (score 0):

Falta comilla en la variable de tipo `CIF`.

En lugar de:

```
data: "{CIF:'12345678a'}",
```

Debe de ser así:

```
data: "{'CIF':'12345678a'}",
```

Comment: Es posible que ese sea el error, sin embargo, yo preferiría poner algo así: `data: '{ "CIF" : "12345678a" }',`, es decir, cambiar las comillas simples por dobles y viceversa ;)